# React Native using Twilio Programmable Chat and RN Gifted Chat

Tags: react-native, twilio-programmable-chat, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm building a mobile app with React Native. I'm using Twilio Programmable Chat along with React Native Gifted Chat.

When testing in the simulator everything works as expected but when I load it on my actual device and try to send a message, it gets sent but then repeated 10-15 second later. This means the message sends over and over until I navigate off the screen to another part of the app.

I haven't put any code here as it works in simulator so I don't know where to even start as I'm not getting any errors to give me a clue.

This is a bit of a weird one and I'm not really sure how to find the actual source of the issue so any help is VERY greatly appreciated.